# Is there anyway to get videojs-record to work on phone?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, videojs-record

Hi so as you can see i have a problem with videojs-recorder, problem is i can't get access to my cam on phone. I use code down below and i am testing it with remote dev tools on chrome. Error is:

VIDEOJS: ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getUserMedia' of undefined

This is my code:

```
    let player;
    const options = {
      controls: true,
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
          plugins: {
              record: {
                  audio: true,
                  screen: true,
                  image: false,
                  maxLength: 3600,
                  debug: true,

              }
          }
    };
    player = videojs("myVideo", options , function(){
          // print version information at startup
          videojs.log('Using video.js', videojs.VERSION,
              'with videojs-record', videojs.getPluginVersion('record'),
              'and recordrtc', RecordRTC.version);
    });
    // error handling
    player.on('deviceError', function() {
        console.log('device error:', player.deviceErrorCode);
    });

    player.on('error', function(element, error) {
        console.error(error);
    });

    player.on('startRecord', function() {
        console.log('started recording!');
    });


    player.on('finishRecord', function() {
        console.log('finished recording: ', player.recordedData);
    });
```

Edit:

Currently i am using 2.1.2 and i am unable to do update.

Comment: u are using an api without providing for its proper construction/config.   you might spend some time on the "getUserMedia" details at :: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

Comment: @RobertRowntree thank your for replay, i will look into it :)

Comment: If anyone is having same issue, in my case solution was to start a secure link so before address type https://